# Why do spherical M2 branes have no net charge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, string-theory, branes, supergravity

In the paper [Invasion of the Giant Gravitons from Anti de Sitter Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003075), the authors claim that

> We are interested in the dynamics of a relativistic spherical membrane moving in $S^4$. The
> membrane has zero net charge but it couples to the background field strength.

M2 branes couple to the background four-form field strength, so I would assume they should have a net charge (especially since it doesn't make sense for one "end" to be positive and the other "end" to be negative since there are no ends!). So how can I see that they should have net zero charge?